# Crop Parent Background via Child

Tags: css

Let's hypothesize we have this:

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div>Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And let's say we have a background on body:

`body { background: var(--complexBackground); }
.page { margin: 5.0em; }
.header { padding: 10px; }`

How to crop the body background so it only appears (As much as possible) within .header?

For example, if it's an image, this exact situation would only show as much of the image as "Content", plus padding if any, would allow, considering the margin. So it'd be 5.0em down the image that the header would use as the background. Though I don't want a solution that only works with images, as other background conditions may come up.

Meanwhile, on the rest of body or .page, the background wouldn't exist.

Would it be possible to give .page a different background for the rest of the page (Since it's likely .page would have to crop it, then have it further cropped by .header, which in theory would mean I'd be able to set background separately)?

Added twist, let's assume .header is fixed: `position: fixed;`... could we make it so that the .header only takes the top of the background, as it originated?

**To recap:**

- **body:** Has background.
- **.page:** Should be able to give everything not overlapped by .header a 
  different background.
- **.header:** Crops body background. Bonus (Not required): If fixed,
  .header carries the original view it had of the background on-load?
- **Solution:** Applies to any background, not just images.

Comment: I guess there's only a javascript solution if you want it exactly that way you described. Anyway. This actually doesnt make any sense. Change your css selectors and/or html.

Comment: It's about consistent experience. JS/jQuery solution is fine. Because of how the appearance is, it's virtually impossible without a hundred different variations to get the exact look I want unless I run the background from top to bottom and have the header adopt the background. Regardless of how that's achieved, it'd require cropping the header area, so there's not a way around it unless I abandon the concept, which I'd rather not. Just because it doesn't make sense to you doesn't mean it doesn't make sense or that it needs to be changed. Just means you're not sure how, or how it'd be useful.